# How to Reset The Pivot Point of a Face in Edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

I have model that I've rotated some of the faces and I want to reset the rotation or the pivot point on that face (in edit mode). How would I accomplish that?

[image]